# Generating the start and end of the month. Swift 2

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimeinterval

I have the following code:

```
func rangeOfPeriod(period: NSCalendarUnit, date: NSDate) -> (NSDate, NSDate) {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var startDate: NSDate? = nil
        var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0

        calendar.rangeOfUnit(period, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: date)

        let endDate = startDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(duration - 1)

        return (startDate!, endDate)
}
```

When i print the following lines:

```
print("Day test = \(rangeOfPeriod(.Day, date: NSDate()))")
print("Week test = \(rangeOfPeriod(.WeekOfYear, date: NSDate()))")
print("month test = \(rangeOfPeriod(.Month, date: NSDate()))")
print("Year test = \(rangeOfPeriod(.Year, date: NSDate()))")
```

All of them work as expected apart from month.

I get 'month test = (2016-03-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2016-03-31 22:59:59 +0000)' as a result and it seems to be missing a hour. For the time for all the others i get '2016-03-26 23:59:59 +0000'.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [first and last day of the current month in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605816/first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-swift)

Comment: daylight saving time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a confusion about the `interval` parameter in the `rangeOfUnit` method.

From the documentation

> ```
> func rangeOfUnit(_ unit: NSCalendarUnit,
>         startDate datep: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDate?>,
>            interval tip: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSTimeInterval>,
>            forDate date: NSDate) -> Bool
> ```
>
> .....
>
> *tip* : Upon return, contains the duration (as `NSTimeInterval`) of the calendar unit `unit` that
>   contains the date `date`

---

For this month (March 2016) due to Daylight Saving Time change the duration is

```
31 * 86400.0 - 3600.0 = 2674800.0
```

That means there is an hour missing, but it's not specified when.

---

To get the end of the month this is more accurate

```
func endOfThisMonth() -> NSDate
{
  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  let components = NSDateComponents()
  components.day = 1
  let startOfNextMonth = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingComponents: components, options: .MatchNextTime)!
  return calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Second, value: -1, toDate: startOfNextMonth, options: [])!
}
```