# How to get first date of month?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I am working on get start and end date from today’s date.

I am getting start and end date of current month by using
formula given by Martin R

[Get first and last day of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605816/first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-swift)

It is working perfectly.

My issue is how to put my custom value in this line

```
let components1 = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)
```

Can I replace my custom month value to this code?

My requirement is:

I have one tableView for months like January, etc.
When I will click TableView I am getting current month according to tableview.

Suppose I click on January, I will get value 1.

So how to get start and end date of month using my custom month value?

My Code

```
 let date = NSDate()
        let calendar   = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"

        //To Get Start Date of Month
        let components1  = calendar.components([.Year,.Day], fromDate: date)
        components1.month = 3
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components1)!
        txtStartDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth)
```

Comment: your customer value only month?

Comment: Just start with `let components = calendar.components([.Year], fromDate: NSDate())` and then set `components.month = <your month>`

Comment: i can select month and year

Comment: Then start with `let components = NSDateComponents()` and set month and year ...

Comment: I click on March that which value display?

Comment: it should display 3

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya actually when i click on tableview i will get value of month.than i have to pass this value to formula by Given Martin R

Comment: this method put didselect method in tableview. please said formula your.

Comment: Plz check my updated question and correct me

Comment: which output display and which output need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123001/discussion-between-bhadresh-kathiriya-and-krutarth-patel).

Comment: @MartinR how can i get 12-09-2016 00:00:00 AND 12-09-2016 23:59:59 from today's date.can you please tell me?

Comment: You have already posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449743/how-to-get-start-and-end-time-of-todays-date-in-ios and accepted an answer, therefore I assume that your problem is solved now.

Comment: i am stuck in time zone.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = "January 2016" // custom value
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"

    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)!)
    let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth))
    //NSLog("%@ : %@", startOfMonth,dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth));
```

Output:

```
01
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question

temp number is month number like if January it will considered as 1.

plz go through this solution to get start and end date from custom values
thanks @Martin R

```
let calendar   = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"

        //To Get Start Date of Month
        let components1 = calendar.components([.Year], fromDate: NSDate())
        components1.month = Int(tempNumber!)!
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components1)!
        txtStartDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth)

        //To Get End Date of Month
        let comps2 = NSDateComponents()
        comps2.month =  1
        comps2.day   = -1
        let endOfMonth = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(comps2, toDate: startOfMonth, options: [])!
        txtEndDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(endOfMonth)
```