# how to get start and end time of today's date in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting current date and time by using this code

```
    let today: NSDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "SGT");
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(today))
```

but i want to get start time and end time of today’s date

example : 
`12-09-2016 00:00:00 AND 12-09-2016 23:59:59`

How to get start and end time of current date?

Comment: `NSDate()` gives 'now'. You can utilise `NSDateComponents` and set the `hour` `minute` `second` and `nanosecond` components. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13324633/2710486)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `startOfDayForDate` to get today's midnight date and then get end time from that date.

```
//For Start Date
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")! //OR NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let dateAtMidnight = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

//For End Date
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.second = -1
let dateAtEnd = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: startOfDay, options: NSCalendarOptions())
print(dateAtMidnight)
print(dateAtEnd)
```

**Edit:** Convert date to string

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone (abbreviation: "UTC")! // OR NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let startDateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateAtMidnight)
let endDateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateAtEnd)
print(startDateStr)
print(endDateStr)
```

Comment: Working.but how to take this values in textfield

Comment: What do you mean by "how to take this values in textfield" ? You want to show this date in textField?

Comment: Yes.correct....

Comment: Actually this answer has a problem with the timezone. It will provide the correct answer if you don't specify a timezone, otherwise it will shift the time.

Comment: i have to set singapore timezone

Comment: @EridB Edited timezone as requirements of OP.

Comment: @NDoc yes i need to show values in textfield

Comment: @NDoc I wasn't talking about providing the timezone that OP asked, but I am saying if you provide it, you won't get the correct date with this answer, but you will have: `"Sep 11, 2016, 6:00 PM`, `"Sep 12, 2016, 5:59 PM"`. Try your code in PlayGround

Comment: @EridB i am getting values.
2016-09-11 16:00:00 +0000
2016-09-12 15:59:59 +0000

Comment: Bro if i specify `UTC`as timezone i get correct time as op want i have already checked in playground.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel You need to use timezone `UTC` or localtime zone.

Comment: @EridB Check this screen shot http://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8B1.png

Comment: @NDoc Well that is not correct then. I know that works with the local timezone, I said it in my first comment, but the OP is actually asking about the start of the date which is related to a specific timezone.

Comment: @EridB Check the question op want 00:00:00 and 23:59:00 no by specific time zone.

Comment: @NDoc i write this date because my task is to get record from today's date.so i thought i can find by 00:00:00 and 23:59:00 format.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Then what do you want? Also check edited answer for string date and then assign this string to textField.

Comment: @NDoc i am sending data in format which i mention in my question.my requirement is to get today's date and get start and end time.so i can use this date to retrive data from database

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Have you try with localtime zone or with UTC that will give you time that you want, start will be 00:00:00 and end will be 23:59:00.

Comment: **Don't use** `60*60*24` as the duration of one day. In regions with daylight saving time, a day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours. Use the proper calendar methods, as demonstrated in the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day.

Comment: Thank you everyone for extensive support.

Comment: @NDoc what about if i want time always between  00:00:00 and 23:59:00.

Comment: i don't get your question, time is always between `00:00:00 and 23:59:00`.

Comment: when i try your code i am not getting this value."2016-09-12 18:30:00" to "2016-09-13 18:29:59"

Comment: @NDoc when i choose date from datepicker,my start date is "2016-09-13 12:00:00".i use same code.why?

Comment: You want to set time to some other date selected from datepicker?

Comment: Yes becuase i can select datetime from datepicker

Comment: Can you add new question with datepicker code and what time you want from that date with example. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464326/how-to-get-start-and-end-time-from-datepicker-in-swift

Comment: added new question

Comment: Check my answer properly here i have use `HH` not `hh`, `hh` is for 12 hour format that was your mistake.

Comment: @NiravD. thank you for correct me