# How to customise UIDatePicker to achieve the following output?

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker, picker

[image]

This is the picker that contains the day, date, and month as input, also, in one scroll, is there any way to achieve this kind of functionality from picker/datepicker in iOS?

Comment: What about making it as a UIPickerView instead?

Comment: This can do Using Normal UIPickerView

Comment: How to give this input @AhmadF

Comment: the input should be the days of the current month, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a case, you should add it as a *[UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview)*. Assuming that the issue would be: How to fill its values by the days of the current month? to make it more clear, I would mention it as steps:

- You should get the current month *start* and *end* dates. You could find how to achieve it by checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35021320/5501940).
- You will need to get all days -with the desired format- between the start and the end dates. You could find how to achieve it by checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536738/5501940).
- After getting all days in the current month, you could fill the date picker datasource method easily.

**Implementation:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var currentMonthDays: [String] {
        var array = [String]()

        var date = Date().startOfMonth() // first date
        let endDate = Date().endOfMonth()

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        //fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        fmt.dateFormat = "EEE dd MMM"

        while date <= endDate {
            date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!

            array.append(fmt.string(from: date))
        }

        return array
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(currentMonthDays)
    }

    // Picker View Data Soruce & delegate Methods

    // REMARK: make sure to connect pickerview datasource/delegate to your view controller,
    // I did it from the storyboard
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return currentMonthDays.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return currentMonthDays[row]
    }
}


// Step #1:
extension Date {
    func startOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
    }

    func endOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth())!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the ultimate solution that I wanted

Comment: FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication that this answer is the solution for such an issue for viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Do below steps :- 
1. You have to change date with applying `DateFormatter()`. 
2. Save all dates (string format) in your `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` for your `UIPickerView` `Datasource` method. 
3. Then call `UIPickerView` `Datasource` and `Delegate` methods for fetch your result.

For date conversion you can apply below code.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE dd MMM"
let currentDate = NSDate()

let convertedDateString = dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate as Date)
print("convertedDate: ", convertedDateString)
```

Comment: If its working then accept the answer and give upvote so other SO visitors can apply above code in their code for solving their issues. Thank you.

Comment: I dont see how this produces the visual output he wants

Comment: @Daij-Djan i give a exact solution of issue. For visual output developer have to develop a functionality.

Comment: the question is "How to customise UIDatePicker to achieve the following output?" ... you dont answer it