# Get last week and last month start and end dates

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

Get last week and last month start and end dates.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let date = Date()

//Today date
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(dateString)

//Yesterday
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date)!
print(dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday))

//This week
let startWeek = date.startOfWeek
let endWeek = date.endOfWeek
print(startWeek ?? "not found start date")
print(endWeek ?? "not found end date")

extension Date {//Get this week starts from monday
var startOfWeek: Date? {
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
    return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 2, to: sunday)
}

var endOfWeek: Date? {
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
    return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 8, to: sunday)
}

}

//This month
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-yyyy"
let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(nameOfMonth)

//Last 30days
let last30Days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: date)!
print(dateFormatter.string(from: last30Days))
```

I need last week start date and end date[Start day is Monday and end day is sunday]

And last month start date and end date

Comment: What you meant by **last week and last month start and end dates.** ??

Comment: @dahiya_boy He wants 1/3/2019, 31/3/2019 and 31/3/2019, 6/4/2019

Comment: @ RajeshKumar R, yes you are right

Comment: last month start and end dates https://stackoverflow.com/a/33606288/7250862

Comment: @RajeshKumar R, it's getting **Ambiguous use of 'components'** in this line let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)   My code is let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: date)
        let startOfMonth = Calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
        print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfMonth))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293465-dateinterval) function to calculate the range of dates, it takes a target date, a calendar component and two inout parameters that will be populated with the date and time interval calculated.

```
func dateInterval(of component: Calendar.Component, start: inout Date, interval: inout TimeInterval, for date: Date) -> Bool
```

Here's an example:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let today = Date()

let lastWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: today)
let lastMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: today)

if let lastWeek = lastWeek {
    var startOfLastWeek = Date()
    var interval = TimeInterval(0)

    calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)

    let endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.addingTimeInterval(interval)

    print(startOfLastWeek)
    print(endOfLastWeek)
}

if let lastMonth = lastMonth {
    var startOfLastMonth = Date()
    var interval = TimeInterval(0)

    calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, start: &startOfLastMonth, interval: &interval, for: lastMonth)

    let endOfLastMonth = startOfLastMonth.addingTimeInterval(interval)

    print(startOfLastMonth)
    print(endOfLastMonth)
}
```

If you need to change the first day of the week you can change it in your calendar like this:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday
```

Remember that when you print the date `print(startOfLastMonth)`, it is displayed in UTC, if you want the date printed in your timezone you will have to use a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).

Comment: your code working fine, but when I set date formatter it getting wrong  last month last date.  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            print(dateFormatter.string(from: startOfLastMonth))  Output: 01-03-2019 00:00:00
01-04-2019 00:00:00
            print(dateFormatter.string(from: endOfLastMonth))

Comment: Removing a second (or a day if you want the start of the day) from endOfLastMonth should give you the right date.     
let endOfLastMonth = startOfLastMonth.addingTimeInterval(interval-1)

Comment: Thnak you, Result of call to 'dateInterval(of:start:interval:for:)' is unused Getting this warning in this line Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)

Comment: Except above warning your code working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this call returns a bool that indicates if the calculation was successful. If you need it you can assign it to a variable (let success = Calendar.current.dateInterval...) otherwise you can ignore the result adding _ = before the call (_ = Calendar.current.dateInterval...)

Comment: @ lorenzoliveto, thank you very much to spent your valuable time for me.

Comment: Last week code getting Sunday to Sunday, means 31-03-2019 and 7-04-2019. I need to change last week 1st day Monday ( 01-04-2019 and 7-04-2019) let lastWeek = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: date)
                if let lastWeek = lastWeek {
                    var startOfLastWeek = Date()
                    var interval = TimeInterval(0)
                    _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)
                    let endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.addingTimeInterval(interval) }

Comment: How to change last week first day Monday onwards and last week last sunday.

Comment: last week 1st day getting Sunday, I want to change it Monday. Can you please suggest. (Week starts with Monday and ends with sunday)

Comment: @ LorenzOliveto, your code not working, can you help me to get last week date from Monday.  My code is var dateFormatter:DateFormatter!
    var date:Date!    In **viewDidLoad()**  dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: My complete code in my function  var calendar = Calendar.current
                calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday
                let lastWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())
                if let lastWeek = lastWeek {
                    var startOfLastWeek = Date()
                    var interval = TimeInterval(0)
                    _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)

Comment: let endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.addingTimeInterval(interval)
                    let startWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: startOfLastWeek)
                    let endWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: endOfLastWeek)

Comment: Hello, this is not the way to ask questions on StackOverflow, open a new question so also others can see it and answer.