# How to create Date object with nth date of current month in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to create one Date object with 2nd date of current month. I can only think of following code . But any other way I can do in swift?

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let mytime = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: 2)))
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605816/first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-swift/33606288#33606288) and simply add one day to startOfMonth