# Using NSDate calculations to determine previous and next pay period for bi-weekly pay frequency

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to calculate the next and previous pay days for a user, when given a specified date.

I'm storing two properties for the user like so:

```
public var firstPayDay: NSDate {
    get { return (NSDate(dateNumber: self["firstPayDay"] as! NSNumber)) }
    set(date) {
        self["firstPayDay"] = date.dateNumber()
        self.payDayOfWeek = self.firstPayDay.dayOfWeek(zeroBased: true)! 
                                               // day of week from 0 - 6
    }
}
```

> When first introduced to the app, the user is asked to provide their next pay day. This is stored as an integer, e.g. 20160126 on the user object, and the following convenience is used to convert it to NSDate:
>
> ```
> convenience init(dateNumber: NSNumber) {
>     let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
>     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
>     self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate: dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateNumber.stringValue)!)
> }
> ```

```
public var payDayOfWeek: Int {
    get { return (self["payDayOfWeek"] as! Int) }
    set(dayOfWeek) { self["payDayOfWeek"] = dayOfWeek }
}
```

> When firstPayDay is set, payDayOfWeek is updated using the 0-based (Sunday ⇢ Saturday) index of the weekday.

I can use this method just fine to get the next and previous pay days for *weekly* pay periods like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35022561/1214800), but I'm struggling how to do this for **bi-weekly** pay periods?

To determine the previous and next *bi-weekly* pay days, I would need to calculate in increments of two weeks from the first pay day, then determine where the specified day fits in between the two. How would I do that in code with the two known properties `firstPayDay` and `payDayOfWeek`?

Expected output:

```
user.firstPayDay = NSDate(fromNumber: 20160101) // January 1st, 2016
print(user.payDayOfWeek) // 5 (Friday, inferred from firstPayDay setter)

// For Today, 20160126
print(user.nextPayDayForDate(20160126)) // should return 20160129, the closest Friday an even two weeks from 20160101 and in the future
print(user.prevPayDayForDate(20160126)) // should return 20160115, the closest Friday an even two weeks from 20160101 and in the past

// For Saturday, 20160130
print(user.nextPayDayForDate(20160130)) // should return 20160212, the closest Friday an even two weeks from 20160101 and in the future
print(user.prevPayDayFordate(20160130)) // should return 20160129, the closest Friday an even two weeks from 20160101 and in the past
```

#### Work in Progress

```
internal func nextWeekBasedPayDate(payFrequency: PayFrequency, firstPayDay: NSDate) -> NSDate? {
    let interval: Int = payFrequency == .Weekly ? 7 : 14
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
    guard
        let date: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: interval, toDate: self.previousWeekBasedPayDate(payFrequency, firstPayDay), options: [])! else { return nil }
    return date.at12pm()
}

internal func previousWeekBasedPayDate(payFrequency: PayFrequency, firstPayDay: NSDate) -> NSDate? {
    let interval: Int = payFrequency == .Weekly ? 7 : 14
    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
    guard
        let daysSinceFirstPayDate: Int = calendar.components([ .Day ], fromDate: firstPayDay, toDate: self, options: []).day,
        let daysSincePreviousPayDate: Int = daysSinceFirstPayDate % interval + (daysSinceFirstPayDate < 0 ? interval : 0),
        let date: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -daysSincePreviousPayDate, toDate: self, options: [])! else { return nil }
    return date.at12pm()
}

internal func at12pm() -> NSDate? {
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    return cal.dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: self, options: [])
}
```

Then to calculate a pay period:

```
func currentPayPeriod(payFrequency: PayFrequency, firstPayDay: NSDate) -> [NSDate]? {
    var startDate: NSDate
    var endDate: NSDate
    switch payFrequency {
    case .Monthly:
        startDate = self.startOfMonth()!
        endDate = self.endOfMonth()!
    case .Weekly, .BiWeekly:
        startDate = (self.previousPayDay(payFrequency, firstPayDay: firstPayDay))!
        endDate = (self.nextPayDay(payFrequency, firstPayDay: firstPayDay)?.addDays(-1))!
    case .SemiMonthly:
        startDate = self.startOfMonth()!
        endDate = self.middleOfMonth()!
    }
    return [startDate, endDate]
}
```

This seems to work perfectly:

```
/*
payPeriod   [NSDate]    2 values    
    [0] __NSTaggedDate *    2016-01-24 20:00:00 UTC 0xe41bc5564c000000
    [1] __NSTaggedDate *    2016-01-30 20:00:00 UTC 0xe41bc5d4dc000000
*/
```

Comment: Your date format it is wrong `Y` should be used only for WeekOfYear. You should change it to  `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: Can you please give example input and the corresponding exact desired output!?

Comment: Sure @luk2302, done. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear

Comment: So All you need is to add or subtract 2 weeks from the date you get from the first DayOfWeek date in the month ? dateByAddingUnit .WeekOfYear, -2 or +2

Comment: Not exactly. Updated the exampled for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd store the date as a number instead of a string, since you can't do math on it and you just have to convert it to a string to parse it anyway. So I'm just going to use string dates in this answer.

Also, converting a date to an `NSDate` without considering the time within the day is dangerous, because [it tends to produce wrong answers for some days in some time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24088730/77567). So let's tell the parser to use noon as the time within the day:

```
extension NSDate {
    class func withYMDString(string: String) -> NSDate {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let defaultComponents = NSDateComponents()
        defaultComponents.hour = 12
        defaultComponents.minute = 0
        defaultComponents.second = 0
        dateFormatter.defaultDate = dateFormatter.calendar.dateFromComponents(defaultComponents)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)!
    }
}
```

Now let's consider how to find the prior and next pay dates. We have a reference pay date:

```
let referencePayDate = NSDate.withYMDString("20160101")
```

And we have some date of interest:

```
let someDate = NSDate.withYMDString("20151231")
```

For the purpose of finding the nearest pay dates to `someDate`, it doesn't really matter what day of week the pay dates fall on. A pay date comes every two weeks, which is every fourteen days. So we want to find those dates which are a multiple of fourteen days from `referencePayDate`, and which are nearest to `someDate`. We start by computing the number of days from `referencePayDate` to `someDate`:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
let daysSinceReferencePayDate = calendar.components([ .Day ],
    fromDate: referencePayDate, toDate: someDate, options: []).day
```

Then we round it down to the nearest multiple of 14, toward -∞:

```
let daysSincePriorPayDate = daysSinceReferencePayDate % 14
    + (daysSinceReferencePayDate < 0 ? 14 : 0)
```

(Note that we need to adjust for a negative numerator because of the way Swift computes the remainder.)

From that we can compute the prior pay date:

```
let priorPayDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -daysSincePriorPayDate,
    toDate: someDate, options: [])!
// Result: Dec 18, 2015, 12:00 PM
```

The next pay date is 14 days later:

```
let nextPayDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 14,
    toDate: priorPayDate, options: [])!
// Result: Jan 1, 2016, 12:00 PM
```

Comment: Reading through now, but to answer your first point, it's because I need to perform interval queries on a back end that can't do date comparisons. Either I use an epoch timestamp (which includes the time) or just the date string.

Comment: OK - see work in progress update to my OP. I'm seeing it log the previous pay date, given Sunday as pay day on a bi-weekly basis, `2016-01-25 02:09:54 +0000`. That looks accurate, although the timezone is in UTC. Does this pose a problem? If not, then I think this works perfectly.

Comment: `nextWeekBasedPayDate` is wrong. It just takes the current date plus seven or fourteen days, regardless of whether the current date is a pay date.

Comment: Doh! Yeah I fixed that already; it calls previousDay first. Fixed the OP.